How to combine Vierbein fields?
As far as I understand each Vierbein field $e^{a}_{\mu}$ and $e^{b}_{\nu}$ can be represented by a $4\times4$ matrix that can act on the Minkowski metric $\eta_{ab}$ to give the curved spacetime metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ through $g_{\mu\nu} = e^{a}_{\mu}e^{b}_{\nu}\eta_{ab}$. In this equation, each of the Vierbein fields $e^{a}_{\mu}$ and $e^{b}_{\nu}$ are acting individually on the flat Minkowski metric. Would it be possible to combine the Vierbein fields into a single $4\times4$ representation? If so, how would one do that? I assume a simple matrix multiplication would not work.

There are 4 numbers of 4×4 matrices (the vierbeins) . Are you asking to combine all these 4 4×4 matrices into one 4×4 matrix? That's not possible right?

On the first place Vierbein's transform coordinate components $V^\mu$ of vectors in components $V^a$ which transform consistently under Lorentz transformations:
$$V^a(x) = e^a_\mu(x) V^\mu(x)$$
If the vectors are 4D, then the vierbein can be representated by a 4x4 matrix.
It also allows to construct general tangent vectors:
$$t_a = e^\mu_a(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$$
which are not necessarily holonom. Something similar is possible with 1-forms:
$$\omega^a = e^a_\mu(x) dx^\mu$$
When applied on tensors 2 vierbein's are necessary:
$$g_{\mu\nu} = e^a_\mu e^b_\nu \eta_{ab}$$
where $\eta_{ab}$ is the Minkowski metric, whereas $g_{\mu\nu}$ is a general metric.
So this is already a "tensor product" application of vierbein's which is more complicated than the operation on vectors or forms. If one constructed a single matrix which transforms the coordinate components of the metric tensor in Lorentz-covariant ones, first of all due to the symmetry of the metric tensor one would need a 10x10 matrix. Secondly it would hardly possible to decompose such matrix in single vierbein's which in another situation could be used to transform a vector. So doing something like this is not really of interest.

Hi @Frederic Thomas thanks for your response. Just out of curiosity, how did you get the notion of a $10\times10$ matrix in case one wants to combine the Vierbein matrix representations? In that case, how  does this $10\times10$ matrix act on the $4\times4$ Minkowski metric? Does one need a $10\times10$ representation of the metric?

Just order all components of the metric tensor in a column, but don't put those with the same indices but swapped order not twice, you get a column of 10 elements. This 10-element "vector" is then multiplied by a 10x10 matrix to get another  10-element "vector" constituting the components of the metric tensor in the other representation. Remember the metric tensor has 10 independent elements due its symmetry.
